# Set KeyVault permission to an AAD App in a different tenant works in PowerShell but fails in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to grant access to an AAD app under a different tenant, the command below works:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $rg -ApplicationId $appId -objectId $appObjectId  `
 -PermissionsToSecrets get -PermissionsToCertificates get -BypassObjectIdValidation
```

But the corresponding ARM template implementation doesn't:

```
"type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
"apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
"name": "[parameters('KeyVaultName')]",
"properties": {
     "accessPolicies": {
     {
         "tenantId": "current-tenant-id",
         "objectId": "object-id",
         "permissions": {
            "secrets": [
              "get"
            ]
          }
      },
     {
         "tenantId": "another-tenant-id",  /* Raises: An invalid value was provided for 'accessPolicies' */
         "objectId": "object-id",
         "permissions": {
            "secrets": [
              "get"
            ]
          }
      }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: i would argue that its a permission issue

Comment: Check this blog post - http://blog.codenova.pl/post/azure-key-vault-making-it-right

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to grant access to an AAD app under a different tenant, the command below works

I noticed that you have specified the **BypassObjectIdValidation** parameter. As the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.keyvault/v2.2.0/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy) mentioned about **BypassObjectIdValidation**:

> Enables you to **specify an object ID without validating that the object exists in Azure Active Directory**. Use this parameter only **if you want to grant access to your key vault to an object ID that refers to a delegated security group from another Azure tenant**.

Also, as the description states about [Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.keyvault/v2.2.0/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy) cmdlet:

> The default directory of the Azure subscription in which the key vault resides.
>
> Your Azure account has multiple directories. **If you register an application in a directory other than the default directory, you cannot authorize that application to use your key vault. The application must be in the default directory**.

Based on my understanding, you cannot set KeyVault permission to an AAD App in a different tenant. If you specify the BypassObjectIdValidation parameter, you need to set `objectId` as the object ID of a delegated security group from another Azure tenant.

Additionally, you could leverage [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com/) to get/update the `Access policies` of your existing KeyVault.